# How do I create directory from the user input when using bash script

Tags: bash, shell, loops, directory

The flow user need to follow when running the script

- get input from user
- check if directory exist
- if directory exist display message and ask for new directory
- else create directory

Current code:

```
read -p "enter directory "  DIR

if [ -d "$DIR" ]; then
    echo "directory $DIR already exist"
    sleep 1
elif [ ! -d "$DIR" ]; then
    mkdir -p $DIR
    echo "creating $DIR"
else
    mkdir -p $DIR
    echo "creating $DIR"
fi
```

The question is: How to optimise above code?

Comment: What's your question? Which part do you need help with?

Comment: @RafalNiznik : Under what conditions do you think the final `else` part could be executed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the explanations you provided, here is what I understand:

```
while true; do
    read -p "enter directory "  DIR

    if [ -d "$DIR" ]; then
        echo "directory $DIR already exist"
        sleep 1
    else
        mkdir -p $DIR
        echo "creating $DIR"
        break
    fi
done
```

If you don't need to exit when creating the directory, just remove the `break`.

Comment: thanks very much for help this woks for what i need